# How to add colors of each pixels as metadata to png image file?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, metadata

I have a 4x4 png file. I tried to add all pixels and RGB color info as metadata like below:

```
'Dimension' 4x4
'Coordinates' 0,0;4,4
'Colors'
  x y  R    G   B
  0 0  100  45   50
  0 1   45  85  110
  0 2  240  35    0
  . .  .     .   .
  . .  .     .   .
         .
         .
```

Below is the code:

```
from PIL.PngImagePlugin import PngImageFile, PngInfo
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('DaVinci2.png')

pix = im.load()
w = im.size[0]
h = im.size[1]
pixelcolor=[]
for j in range(h):
    for i in range(w):
        print(i, j, pix[i, j])
        pixelcolor.append([i,j,pix[i, j]])
        print(pixelcolor)

metadata = PngInfo()
metadata.add_text("Dimension", '4x4')
metadata.add_text("Pixels", 0,0,4,4) #coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2
metadata.add_text("Colors", pixelcolor)

im.save("NewPath.png", pnginfo=metadata)
im = PngImageFile("NewPath.png")
```

Below is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hilmi\Desktop\Python\My exerises\Pixeldivide\metadata.py",
line 18, in <module>
    metadata.add_text("Pixels", 0,0,4,4) #coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2
TypeError: PngInfo.add_text() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but
6 were given
```

How should I modify the code to succeed?

Comment: What's the purpose of saving this info which is already in the file anyway please? Your question implies your method didn't work, was there an error message? What happened? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  My aim is learning metadatas. After that I want to save this info as a readable file. I added the error to my question.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you pass too many arguments into the function. I assume each line of metadata should be a single string, not 4 integers.

Comment: As @Cris said, you're not calling the `add_text()` method with the proper arguments per its [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PIL.html?highlight=PngInfo#PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngInfo.add_text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most simply use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to embed your values into a single string like this:

```
metadata.add_text('Pixels', f'0,0,{w},{h}')
```

As regards building the colour string, something like:

```
colourstring = 'x y R G B'
for j in range(h):
   for i in range(w):
      r, g, b = pix[i,j]
      colourstring += f'\n{i},{j},{r},{g},{b}'
```

And then:

```
metadata.add_text("Colors", colourstring)
```

Comment: It would more efficient to accumulate each substring in a list and then concatenate them all together in a single `colourstring = '\n'.join(substrings)`. (But this is otherwise a working solution,)